# Reverse of os.path.normcase on Windows

Tags: python, path, filenames, case-sensitive

Is there a simple way to get the "real" case sensitive path from a all lower case path.
Like the reverse of os.path.normcase.

For example, consider the directory:

```
c:\StackOverFlow
```

If I have the following snippet, how to obtain d_real?

```
>>> import os
>>> d = os.path.normcase('C:\\StackOverFlow') # convert to lower case
>>> d
'c:\\stackoverflow'
>>> d_real = ... # should give 'C:\StackOverFlow' with the correct case
```

Comment: `os.path.join('c:','stackoverflow')` gives you `c:stackoverflow`, *not* `c:\stackoverflow`, as explained in the docs (= path relative to current directory on specified drive).

Comment: Yep, I did not check my example code. Will fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider this solution *simple*, but what you can to is:

```
import os
d = os.path.normcase('C:\\StackOverFlow')
files = os.listdir(os.path.dirname(d))
for f in files:
  if not d.endswith(f.lower()):
    continue
  else
    real_d = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(d), f)
```

It's probably not efficient (depending on the number of files in the directory). It needs tweaking for the path-components (my solution really only corrects the case of the file name and doesn't care about the directory names). Also, maybe `os.walk` could be helpful to traverse down the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by chaining `GetShortPathName` and `GetLongPathName`. This can in theory not work because you can disable short filenames on Windows with some configuration setting. Here's some sample code using ctypes:

```
def normcase(path):
    import ctypes
    GetShortPathName = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetShortPathNameA
    GetLongPathName = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLongPathNameA
    # First convert path to a short path
    short_length = GetShortPathName(path, None, 0)
    if short_length == 0:
        return path
    short_buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(short_length)
    GetShortPathName(path, short_buf, short_length)
    # Next convert the short path back to a long path
    long_length = GetLongPathName(short_buf, None, 0)
    long_buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(long_length)
    GetLongPathName(short_buf, long_buf, long_length)
    return long_buf.value
```

Comment: This works just great EXCEPT that the drive or network component of a path can still be an arbitrary case.  I found it useful to add 
`parts = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.normcase(path))`
`path = parts[0].upper()+parts[1]`
to the beginning of the function so that I would have uppercase drive letters and lowercase network paths.

Comment: Note: For this file system dependent solution first check if **short filename generation** is switched off on Windows volumes (`fsutil.exe 8dot3name query C:`) - which meanwhile is recommended for performance unless 16bit apps are still feasting.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard lib only, this one works on all path parts / subdirs (except drive letter):

```
def casedpath(path):
    r = glob.glob(re.sub(r'([^:/\\])(?=[/\\]|$)', r'[\1]', path))
    return r and r[0] or path
```

And this one handles UNC paths in addition:

```
def casedpath_unc(path):
    unc, p = os.path.splitunc(path)
    r = glob.glob(unc + re.sub(r'([^:/\\])(?=[/\\]|$)', r'[\1]', p))
    return r and r[0] or path
```

Comment: @Alecz, files are the main use case. Cannot reproduce the problem. Example? Known: It doesn't uppercase a possible drive letter (and UNC service name); doesn't convert slash -> backslash. it doesn't do anything on files / dirs which do not really exist now (existence of just partial path).  Or maybe you used a test path with false/missing backslash escaping or missing raw string prefix r - e.g.  `"some\\false\rawpath.txt"` .

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this either. It works perfectly, I think this is a very neat solution. I will delete my other comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dirty hack approach,

```
import glob
...
if os.path.exists(d):
    d_real = glob.glob(d + '*')[0][:len(d)]
```

Comment: glob.glob(d+'*') returns an empty list on Windows (at least for me)

Comment: @jhwist, I tested it on Windows and it works. What did you use for `d`?

Comment: Hmmm, could be some mixup of cygwin-style paths, my `d = "c:/existing_file"`

Answer (score -1):

Definitely ugly, but fun:

```
def getRealDirPath(path):
    try:
        open(path)
    except IOError, e:
        return str(e).split("'")[-2]
```

Of course:

- works only with dirs
- will be buggy if dir cannot be open for another reason

But can still be useful if you don't need it for "life or death" kind of code.

Tried to grep the standard lib to find how they found the real path but couldn't find it. Must be in C.

That was the dirty hack of the day, next time we will use a regexp on the stacktrace just because we can :-)